# FSK demodulator by integration if the samples per symbols is 2

Tags: modulation, demodulation, fsk

Say I have a binary FSK with `+f` and `-f` frequencies and I have two samples per symbol.

Let's consider the "1) multiply with `+f`/`-f` then 2) integrate over the number of samples per symbol, 3) take absolute value, 4) take the difference" demodulator.

Lets call this type of demodulator `Integrating FSK Demodulator`.

If I have only two samples per symbol, then is the `Integrating FSK Demodulator` the same as if I would just use a differential FM demodulator (which takes 2 consecutive samples into account) ?

If they are different, what is the difference ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but in my opinion to answer your question you should find out: i. are `Integrating Demodulator` and `Differential Demodulator` has different structure but contain the same components; ii. does all components perform linear transformation? If it's true then they both perform equal transformations (in my opinion).

Comment: `Integrating demodulator` is non linear due to the "taking absolute value". `Differential demodulator` is on the other hand linear. So probably they are different, but I am not sure.

Comment: Or wait http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/repository/revisions/master/entry/gr-analog/lib/quadrature_demod_cf_impl.cc#L70 this seems non linear actually. Why is the `Differential demodulator` implementation in gnu-radio.

Comment: Correction, 'Why' = ', which' in previous comment, but I could not edit it, due to being too old.